# How to validate mandatory fields in two forms with one submit button in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have two forms and only one submit  button.And each form have some mandatory fields then how i submit the form1 alone??Please anyone help me to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id of form to be submitted in following function:

```
function submitForm(formID)
{
    $("#"+formID).trigger('submit');
}
```

Call this function when a button is clicked.

The button should have something like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="if(condition for form1){submitForm('form1Id');} else {submitForm('form2Id');}" value="Save" />
```

Comment: How to pass formID  in button onclick??

Comment: See the updated answer with:
`<input type="button" onclick="if(condition for form1){submitForm('form1Id');} else {submitForm('form2Id');}" value="Save" />`